# Logging, do you do it?

Tags: coding-standards, debugging, logging

Back on my theme of late: interview questions.  Was recently asked to describe a time I'd used logging.

My first instinct was to respond with compiler warnings set to full and error-out.  What he was interested in was the use of logging as a debugging tool.

Unfortunately I couldn't think of one at the time except the one I was assigned because clients where having issues connecting to license servers and support wanted a log.

Thinking more clearly now though...I realized that I *used* to use logging a lot, and still do in little experimental projects.  I still use it when developing on Unix systems, but not so much on Windows.  Why?  Because as much as I despise Visual Studio and think their compiler is maybe one of the worse around (I run into numerous bugs and issues with it every day), they got the debugger right!  If I could put Visual Studio's debugger on gcc built executables I absolutely would.   Add to this the use of unit testing to bring things into focus, I simply haven't needed logging very much.

On the other hand, maybe I'm really missing out.  I have occasionally used it, and in fact some things that aren't exactly "logging" seem to me very similar.  For instance, in debug mode the custom widget I created for this drawing application draws a bunch of extra visual clues representing bounding boxes and hot-spots.  I also make very heavy use of assertions and exceptions.

I do have a bunch of mock classes that "log" but they're never used in the real program.  For example, I have a custom drawing context wrapper that allows me to use the same drawing code for various UI API's.  I have a version of it that simply spits out all the commands it receives to a string that I then compare to expected results.  I use this to unit test drawing code.

If I where to use logging as a debugging tool I would want to do so in a consistent, standardized manner.  On the other hand I'm at a bit of a loss to think of one.  I suppose if I where writing something that surrounded network communication and such I would find it very necessary to have debugging logs and various verbosity outputs.  On the other hand I write fairly simple UI programs by comparison.

So, do you use logging?  What do you use it for?  How does logging fit in your coding standards?

Comment: What compiler errors? I can't say that I've ever seen an honest .Net compiler error.

Comment: I write in C++.  I turn warning level to 4 (VS's top level) and then turn off the individual, useless warnings like, "couldn't create an assignment operator for XXX object that's never, ever copied."  With gcc you need -pedantic, -Wall, and a few others to get the same effect.

Comment: How do I turn a question into a wiki?  I don't see how I can accept an answer for this.  They're all very good but it's mostly opinion with some obvious disagreement :P

Comment: Yes, of cause. :)

Comment: "Logging, do you do it?" From another version of Pulp Fiction, I suppose :))))

Answer (score 15):

I work in an environment where we cannot expect errors to be reproducible or be able to attach a debugger to the program.

This has lead to a very defensive programming style, where we basically log a lot of things on the lowest level, which is then enabled when problems are expected or we are in a test phase.  The next higher log level is a lot less verbose and is enough to see that processing is taking place, and what is being processed.  This is the level for stable production.

For Java you also need to make your stack traces as telling as possible since this is a single unit which can contain a *lot* of information.  By suitable catching and wrapping in a new exception with information about the execution environment you can see parameters, full file names, iterator values etc. but only see it when something goes wrong.   This is perhaps the most powerful post-mortem mechanism available today.

Answer (score 14):

For any program/system of sufficient complexity, logging is absolutely vital.  This becomes especially true when your device, application, etc., can be installed and used in odd environments or in conjunction with service providers over which you have little or no control (e.g. telecom, "cloud" providers,...).

In a complex system, it may be impossible to test or qualify every possible scenario for every release of your code.  In one system our team was working on, we enumerated over 15,000 separate use cases.  As clever as anyone thinks they may be ("I prefer not to write bugs"), you will never cover every possible case with perfect certainty that nothing else was affected by seemingly minor changes.

Logging provides the means to detect error conditions, and more importantly, what lead to the error condition being exercised.

On release, log levels should be set high so that only the most important messages get logged, but that threshold should be easily configurable so that a customer exhibiting problems can lower that value and provide more details to those supporting the product.  Likewise, it is important that your system is responsible for cleaning up its own mess -- make sure you either use the underlying system's log system (`syslog` or `SNMP`) or write your own so that your log files don't overwhelm the host by filling up disks and so on.

I would prefer not to write bugs as well, but we're all human, and the more people you add to a project the more complex it becomes.  If you're building something which may eventually become large and/or complex, get a decent logging system in early.  You'll be thankful for it later.

Comment: So, for something as complicated as MS Word (which is as complex as you can get) - where is the log? This is nonsense.

Comment: Never said I don't write bugs :P  I've just found that logging has never appear to me as something that would be of major use except maybe in some few areas.  How does logging fit into your team's standards?  Is there some criteria you use that says a function needs to produce a log message?

Comment: MS Word logs to the event log of the operating system, along with all other microsoft office applications.

Comment: @Crazy: All error conditions are logged.  We have a dual-level log, one with just the messages, and another linked log which has file / line / parameters / extra information.  A special argument is given in the log messages which would be appropriate for end users to see (as opposed to jargon-rich, context-sensitive information used by support).  This isn't as onerous as it sounds if you use exceptions and the handler is tasked with getting debug info and doing the actual logging.  Those areas which require special log messages help the code to document itself.

Comment: It doesn't do so very often, I will admit maybe its a bit of a stretch, but microsoft word has a very strong code base that has been around a good amount of time and is supported by a huge and talented team.  It is also not transactional, isn't communicating over the network, etc.  I would also be willing to bet that during testing MS Word DOES perform a fair amount of logging.  The rules for what gets logged are probably changed for the release build.  This is pure conjecture, but I wouldn't be suprised.

Comment: @Neil - I don't want to be argumentative, but a word processor is far from the most complex application: think PBXes, backbone routers, backend cloud management systems, embedded systems of all kinds, etc.

Comment: @John It logs start ups and fatal errors. That is not what the OP was asking about, I think?

Comment: Neil I am going to have to concede to you on the Microsoft Word issue.

Comment: @Mark I've trained people who write backbone switches. And yes, for them I would write logs (see my answer here). However, I dispute that a switch is more complex than a WP, except possibly by accretion.

Comment: I think what it boils down to is that logging is more useful for some types of applications and less useful for others.  For example, if you administer SharePoint there is a folder in its InetPub directory just for log files.  IIS and SQL Server are two other examples  of applications that use logging very heavily.  I think as far as production code goes, it is probably more critical for multi-user network based applications.  A lot of applications use logging for security / audit purposes as well.

Comment: I still contend that logging is often useful during development and testing of nearly any type of application.

Comment: @John Well, if it works for you. But it doesn't for me, or for anyone I have ever worked with.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is a "best practice" or anything.  To each their own.  I often find it useful.

Answer (score 7):

So first I work in large scale embedded systems not small ones that have no memory or tools, although I have worked on those as well.  Basically I work on something that resembles a server but is not.  Here are the uses and reasons for using logs:

- With many many systems in the field rarely, if ever, can you attach a debugger so a history of how you got where you are is invaluable.
- Not often can you have a debugger on all of your systems in test so again history is important.
- Some things a debugger can't really capture like how the system runs over time.  Are there things that happen that are not bugs but you need to be aware of and potentially do something about.
- If I took away your debugger today how would you solve a problem?  I think debuggers are great but not always the best tool for the problem.  It helps to have more than 1 tool in the toolbox.
- Collecting use patterns.
- Working on multiple systems that are constantly interacting with one another.  A debugger makes this very hard where logging, providing you have a common time source, makes it very easy to tie these things together.
- Working on something that is real time and you cannot halt the CPU because that would cause everything else around it to alter their behavior.

Comment: Well, if you took away my debugger I'd be stuck with using logs and I'd probably create a coding standard bordering on, "log every step you perform."  This would be completely impractical so I'd have to figure something out and probably devise a whole slew of verbosity levels, standardizing when and how to use each one but logging basically everything at some level.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: and after a while you would find that you cannot keep all those verbosity levels straight in your head and will start to whittle them down... We have actually done away with the verbosity levels. Instead we use several focused logs: Configuration/Customisation (our services are highly configurable and without info on what classes/data they use and load, we have no hope of interpreting user reports and/or knowing what is going on), User activity, Errors, (Execution) Statistics, Service (for our Windows services apps), General and Debug (!)

Answer (score 3):

I use logging fairly often, especially for applications that are heavily dependent upon unmanaged resources that I have less control over (network I/O for example), and for applications that are difficult to debug properly from within Visual Studio.  There are also things that you might want to log in the production environment that you can't log just through debugging, such as user activity, unexpected occurances / exceptions, etc.

For example, at work I recently wrote an application for data transfer.  I had to figure out a way to transfer data from an external server that I control to a server within a government network that I control.  Large amounts of data have to be transferred daily.  I exposed the external data by developing some web services for the external server.  Then I wrote an application that is scheduled to run periodically on the internal server.  The internal server passes authentication information and requests for specific data to the external server via SOAP headers.  The external server then returns the serialized data over HTTPS via XML.  Because there is a large amount of data involved here, the fact that we have a contractual requirement to keep the data up to date and available on the government network, and because of the fact that I am relying on ISP networks which I have little to no control over, I need to be able to log what goes on with the data transfers so that I can troubleshoot issues.  The data transfer software keeps its own logs and also logs events to the event viewer for the server.  Then I expose this data via an intranet website so that I can quickly check the status and health of the data transfer system and the internal database.

I also use logging for security purposes in my production applications.  Some of my web apps log user activity for example, and most of my web apps will log any exceptions that they encounter into a SQL Server database so that I can catch and fix bugs quickly.

Another scenario where I recently used logging was when I needed to quickly install some event handling routines on our SharePoint server.  I didn't have time to set up a proper virtualized environment for sharepoint or a test server either.  I added the SharePoint.dll to a project and wrote the code, read through it meticulously and made sure it compiled, but I didn't have the proper environment to actually run the code and attach it to a debugger.  So as I was developing the application I would periodically install the assemblies to GAC on the server and register them with sharepoint using an in-house utility that I wrote.  I had the event handlers write a lot of informatino to the event viewer on the server so that I could see that they registered with SharePoint and were working properly.

I think I worked on some InfoPath projects before where a couple of them could not be attached to a debuger for whatever reason as well.  I think in that case I simply wrapped DEBUG pre-processor directives around certain parts of the code while I was debugging and troubleshooting so that it would pop-up messageboxes to let me know what was going on.  I'm sure we've all done that before.  That is basically how I debug javascript as well (with alert boxes that I comment out later, lol).

As far as common practices go....one thing that I always do in all of my .NET classes is override ToString().  My ToString() override generally returns all important state data for my type (properties and member fields, etc.).  This is useful for a lot of reasons, and logging is certainly one of them.  If you are trying to hunt down an issue or keep track of things in the production environment you can leverage ToString() a lot in order to log a printout of a types state at any given time.

You can use the EventLog class in System.Diagnostics if you are a .NET developer to write straight to the Event log of the system if your code has the appropriate permissions.  You can also use System.Diagnostics.Debug and System.Diagnostics.Trace for logging purposes.  Trace is useful because you can write directly to the output window in Visual Studio which goes hand-in-hand with debugging.  You can also create your own Performance Counters for your application for use with the Performance Monitor mmc snap-in in Windows.  In reference to your question, you can see that Microsoft considers logging to be a common requirement for a given peice of software, in fact, many if not most of their applications employ some type of logging.

So to answer your question, yes, logging can be very useful, and is in fact very common.

Answer (score 2):

I've used logging as a method of low level audit tracking for a webservice.  Each request that came in I logged to a file with some small logging of what action was taken etc.  The log files were periodically purged by scheduled jobs.  I found this handy to identify issues with other peoples data that was sent and initially helped iron out any issues/cases I hadn't written.

If I was going to suggest any standards around the logging I would probably suggest just being consistant with your output columns and standard information as this may help for bulk parsing or searching etc if required further down the track.

Answer (score 2):

I like logging, log4net rules, here are various thing things I've used it for.

- To trace through multi-threaded code and identify timing errors
- To demonstrate to customers that functionality is complete at the end of a sprint even when there is no UI
- To selectively verify the functionality of different components
- Redirecting the log output to something like Growl so that I can see internal messages in real time.
- To force myself to think in terms of what a business person might want to see in a log (not a lot of point in logging "enter method, exit method messages", a trace tool and a IL rewriter can do that.
- To generate an audit log (though I'd prefer something like event sourcing for that)

Answer (score 1):

As a debugging tool - never. I prefer not to write bugs in the first place. But if you are writing a multi-threaded transactional stock exchange server (or something similar), where OTHER PEOPLES activities may cause problems , then a log is handy in the blame game.

So, log external inputs, transactions, and your outputs, but nothing below that level, otherwise the logs become incomprehensible and slow things down too much.

Comment: And how do you convince others your code is bug-free?

Comment: @Thorbjorn I use these cunning things called  ... tests.

Comment: @nbt, and how do you convince others your tests are comprehensive?

Comment: So, you're a genius who never creates bugs, but you need logging to show that all bugs are the fault of other people who are dumber than you? :rolleyes:

Comment: @Thorb, by using tools that calculate code coverage?

Comment: @Pavel, how do you convince others that even though all code is covered, it does not have any bugs?

Comment: @Thorb by not having any in production.  Still, how could logging help to convince others?

Comment: @Pavel, I am not the one arguing that I do not write bugs in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I've used logging a few times.  I had a bug once that could only be reproduced on a user's machine with their data.  No way to attach a debugger and see what's going on, so I put in some logging statements around where I thought the problem was taking place, sent the build to them, got the results back, put in more logging where the log indicated the bug was happening to narrow it down further, and so on. After 4 or 5 iterations of this the the nature of the bug became obvious and I was able to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I've certainly used it for rare, individual cases when it seemed the best way to figure out WTF was going on.  Not in my regular set of tools though.

Answer (score 1):

I write code per my functional requirements.  If the requirements include logging then I write logging.  If they do not then I do not include undocumented features.  If I am doing something that does not require logging and I really feel that it should then I talk with the PM.  There may be business reasons to or not to log.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I find it very useful for several kinds of things:

- Working with very large data files. When you're looking to see what's being misinterpreted in a 30 GB input to cause some state to change and the program to go south, hitting the same breakpoint a million times isn't an option.
- Working with networking code. If you sit for a couple of minutes staring at a debugger and puzzling over what's going on, the connection will drop.
- Dealing with complex code somebody else wrote. Many times, a client will want a bug fix yesterday, and there's not really time to become an expert or do anything more than a band-aid. In skanky code, any number of dumb things could lead to a given bug; logging the heck out of things will often tell you *which* dumb thing is leading to your particular bug.
- Turning intermediate binary data into something more human-readable than a debugger will do.
- Working on embedded systems, where you compile on a desktop and transfer binaries to the target hardware, and the target hardware doesn't have a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

As a tester, I use logging extensively as a debugging tool.  Debuggers are great when the bugs you encounter are reproducible, but don't do you any good if the error is only hit once and can't be repeated the next day (due to unknown parameters).  In that case, you need more information about what, precisely, was happening in the environment so you can have a better chance of reproducing that issue.  Ability to log probably ranks right up there with ability to mock for testability, depending on your application.

Coding standards:  Have multiple levels of logging:  Normal levels are an 'error' level, a 'Standard' level, and a 'Debug' or 'Trace' level.  Log all exceptions in "Error", including stack traces; major program state changes (e.g., restarting a service) in "Standard"; and relatively tiny details in "Debug" mode.  Have Error and Standard on by default unless there is a reason to turn them off.

Debug mode should generally be turned off except for testing or when gathering information on a potential issue, but should have enough information to give a pretty good picture of the program status; log to this liberally with file identifiers, data, and updates on what the program is doing.  Some people will actually log every function being called.  Note that extreme logging can affect performance, so you may want to turn off your debug logging when performance testing.

Move log files into an archive folder and start a new log file automatically every so often, so that the files don't get too long to be usable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite amazed to hear that everyone doesn't use logging for debugging. If you don't use logging for debugging then answer the question, "How do you figure out what went wrong when the user tells you I was performing activity X and then the system crashed but they don't really know what they did and of course you can't duplicate the problem" OR "When bugs are intermittent and may or may not happen for weeks or months".

I guess if you don't owe your customer quality then it would be ok to just blow their problem off, but when your contract requires you to fix problems then I don't see any other way to give timely fixes for obscure problems other than using log files.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason I've used logging is where I simply can't trust users to give accurate details of what they were doing when the "error" occurred.

If I have logs then I pretty much just need who they were and when it was and I can go and see what they were actually doing, not what they think they were doing.

As our product is used by largely non-technical users this is essentially all the time.

Defining what to log is hard though and is largely an evolutionary process. You make a reasonable first stab and then it gets enhanced as particular code / areas are found to be problematic. Taking your lead from your system test results can help as they're obviously indicative of actual problems which have been seen - yes they may have been fixed in my experience issues clump around certain functions and code (usually as a result of complexity) so if you've seen an issue in one area I'd suggest that you're more likely to further issues there than at some random location.

One thing I would always log - all input and output for any integration with third party systems. First thing the other vendor asks for when you raise a problem.